# Get local time of user around the globe and show in local timezone format to other timezone user

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I ran into trouble while dealing with date and time using php and mysql. I am trying to store local time of user's timezone as a timestamp on mysql db and would like it to convert back to normal date and time at the time of output.

This is the first time I am dealing with date and time.

As I understand: I can't rely on PHP's `time()` as it returns servers time according to server's timezone and the same case with mysql `current_timestamp`.

I can use the javascript to get user's local timezone and then can use `date_default_timezone_set()` for each session.

If I am doing right, now the confusion starts.

As you can understand the users will come from around the globe, so if two users (one from US and another from India) do something at the same time, will it show each others time as identical or it will show some difference? I mean it shouldn't show Indian user that the US user has done something few hours ago as the US user done at same time.

Please let me know if I don't understand these things properly.

What I want to achieve is, the output of the time should show in local time format. Ex: any time should show in IST format for Indian user and other country respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to achieve this is to store date in a database in a standard format (eg. GMT).

After getting user's timezone through javascript, you may convert date to user's timezone & display accordingly.